# Combine two json arrays into one json array where the data will be completely merged into one single Json in react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

First Array contains the below array of elements

```
"Data": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Driver": "Assigned",
}
{
      "ID": 2,
      "Name": "PQR",
      "Driver": "UnAssigned",
}
```

Second Array is of different set of data

```
"Data": [
        {
          "Updated": "KLM",
          "Date": "22/01/2020",
    }
    {
          "Updated": "PQR",
          "Date": "23/01/2020",
    }
{
          "Updated": "OOO",
          "Date": "23/07/2020",
    }
```

I want the final json as below

```
    "Data": [
        {
          "ID": 1,
          "Name": "XYZ",
          "Driver": "Assigned",
          "Updated": "KLM",
          "Date": "22/01/2020",
    
    }
    {
          "ID": 2,
          "Name": "PQR",
          "Date": "23/01/2020",
          "Updated": "PQR",
          "Date": "23/01/2020",
    }
 {
          "ID": 2,
          "Name": "PQR",
          "Driver": "UnAssigned",
          "Updated": "PQR",
          "Date": "23/01/2020",
    }
 {
          "ID": "",
          "Name": "",
          "Driver": "",
          "Updated": "OOO",
          "Date": "23/07/2020",
    }
```

If both the arrays are of different lengths, the field should go as blank like the last one. How can we do in reactjs

Comment: You could use a tool like `lodash` which has built in functions for working with and combining collections. You could also loop over the longer array and create a new array updated with elements from the first

Comment: I wonder the second element of your final json is correct

Comment: The example arrays are 2 and 3 elements long, but the output has 4 elements. We may need more clarification. I'm also curious about how these are stored in the first place that would allow the data to be ordered correctly but not stored together on some key like the `ID`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I wasn't looking to store and send/receive data based on the combined json. I wanted to temporarily add that in an array/json and export the whole as an excel with two rows with the above keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [zip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/) like functionality available in Python.

I created the below snippet that should be of help.

```js
const firstArray = [
    {
        ID: 1,
        Name: "XYZ",
        Driver: "Assigned",
    },
    {
        ID: 2,
        Name: "PQR",
        Driver: "UnAssigned",
    },
];

const secondArray = [
    {
        Updated: "KLM",
        Date: "22/01/2020",
    },
    {
        Updated: "PQR",
        Date: "23/01/2020",
    },
    {
        Updated: "OOO",
        Date: "23/07/2020",
    },
];

// get an empty object from first array with "" as values
firstSchema = Object.keys(firstArray[0]).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = "";
    return acc;
}, {});

// get an empty object from second array with "" as values
secondSchema = Object.keys(secondArray[0]).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = "";
    return acc;
}, {});

// create an empty schema object merged with both above schemas
emptySchema = { ...firstSchema, ...secondSchema };

const zip = (a, b) =>
    Array.from(Array(Math.max(b.length, a.length)), (_, i) => ({
        ...emptySchema,
        ...a[i],
        ...b[i],
}));

console.log(zip(firstArray, secondArray));
```

Also, as user Explosion Pills commented above, you should maybe look into how your data is stored so you can have the `ID` key in the second data set too.